# Column name as second parameter in Full-text search CONTAINS or FREETEXT

Tags: sql, full-text-search, sql-server-2012

Is there any chance to put column name instead of fixed string expression in `CONTAINS()` or `FREETEXT()` clause of Full-text search?

I need to use their functionality but I don't have to hardcode string expressions but to check  against some values in some column.

Basic example:

Two tables, one of them contains some large texts, and other contains words that need to be in those texts. Also I need to find weight of every occurence...

I need something as

```
...
WHERE CONTAINS(Column1, Column2)
```

or

```
...
WHERE FREETEXt(Column1, Column2)
```

Comment: Would a sub query work?

Comment: No, I have tried that already.

Comment: Any news on the solution for this? I find myself with the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would be helpful:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FindSomething 
AS  
BEGIN

  DECLARE @query varchar(...)   
  select @query =  'SELECT [...] WHERE [build me dynamically in cursor]'

  exec (@query) 
END
```